# Powershell Add Local User

Tags: powershell

i would like to create a Powershell Gui Script with the possibility to create a local user. The question here is, why does the code ask for a parameter? With -nopassword it works.

Code:

```
    $button_BenutzerErstellen_OnClick=
{
$textBox6.Text
$textBox7 = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force


                if (($handler_textBox6.Text -eq 0) -or
            ($handler_textBox7.TextLength -eq 0)) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Bitte füllen Sie alle Kriterien aus." , "Combat 19")

         }else{
            New-LocalUser $textBox6.Text -Password $textBox7 -Description $textBox1.Text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `Text` property on `TextBox`es:

```
New-LocalUser $textBox6.Text -Password $textBox7 -Description $textBox1.Text
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does the code ask me for a String? -nopassword work's, but with password it ask's me for a string.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to give string value for Password property of New-LocalUser cmdlet which is not valid expected data type.
Remove this:

```
$textBox7 = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

And change **else** statement to this:

```
    New-LocalUser $textBox6.Text -Password $($textBox7.Text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) -Description $textBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user the **Net User** also as an oneliner

```
NET USER username "password" /ADD
```